# Как можно увеличить быстродействие данного кода?

Tags: java

Задача: 
Two arrays are called similar if one can be obtained from another by swapping at most one pair of elements in one of the arrays.

Given two arrays a and b, check whether they are similar.

```
boolean areSimilar(int[] a, int[] b) {
        if (Arrays.equals(a,b)){
            return true;
        }
        int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
        boolean fl = true;
    label:for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            for (int j = i + 1; j < c.length; j++){
                int tmp = c[j];
                c[j] = c[i];
                c[i] = tmp;
                if (!Arrays.equals(c,b)){
                    fl = false;
                    c[i] = c[j];
                    c[j] = tmp;
                }else{
                    fl = true;
                    break label;
                }
            }
        }
        return fl;
    }
```

Можно ли как-нибудь увеличить быстродействие конкретного куска кода? Если нет, то буду рад увидеть какие-нибудь другие идеи, которые окажутся лучше для данной задачи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение имеет кубическую сложность - а это жуть медленно. А решается она за линейное время.

Алгоритм.

- Проверям размеры. Они должны совпасть.
- Пробегаем по массиву и считаем элементы, которые отличаются, их индексы записываем в массив.
- Если кол-во отличий стало больше 2 (при проходе по массиву), дальше даже не нужно сверять - можно выходить, условие нарушено.
- Имея массив из двух индексов, проверям, равны ли они при обмене (массивы менять не нужно даже, просто два сравнения).
- Готово!